# __init__.py in python 3.6 vs python 2.7

Tags: python, module

I'm updating a module I wrote in Python 2.7 to Python 3.6. I have a concern on the way the `__init__.py` is processed in both versions of the language.

In particular, my `__init__.py` looks something like this:

```
from FT_optimize import *
from FuzzyVars import *
from FuzzyTree import *
```

When I upload the package from Python 2.7. With something like this:

```
import FuzzyTree as ft
```

I can access the namespace of all the modules declared in the `__init__.py`. Something like:

```
ft.optmize_partition(ft.FuzzyTree)
```

However the same code in Python 3.6 reports an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'FuzzyTree' has no attribute 'optimize_partition'
```

Any idea?

From the Python documentation I haven't see any difference of criteria.

Comment: is your current working directory the directory where the `__init__` is placed or did you install the package?

Comment: Now I found the solution. It seems that in python3 you must declare the relative route to the files in the package even when they are in the same directory. So I wrote: from .FT_optimize import * (and the same for the other imports) and now everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem (see my comment) is declaring the relative route to all the modules in the **init**.py including those that are in the same directory.

Therefore, following the previous example, the **init**.py now looks:

```
from .FT_optimize import *
from .FuzzyVars import *
from .FuzzyTree import *
```

(You should realize the dot before the name of the module).
And now everything works.